# What are the Force powers available in Clone Wars Adventures?

Tags: star-wars-clone-wars-adventures

I played the free version of Clone Wars Adventures online and was given a Jedi avatar, with Attack 1: Lightsaber slash and shortly gained Attack 2: Force push. I noticed 6 other boxes for Force powers. Does anybody know what they are?